# Files missing after copying between harddrives

Tags: storage

I removed the hard drive from my Toshiba laptop running Windows 8.1 and connected it to my desktop running Windows 7. I copied some files from the desktop to the hard drive. It was showing up perfectly when connected to the desktop but when I connected it back to my laptop, these files are missing. It is not even showing as used space. How do I find the files?

Comment: Sounds like you "moved" them instead of "copying" them.  Drag and drop can surprise you like that sometimes (assuming that's the method you used)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, i cut and pasted it, which is why I am more worried because the original files are also lost

Comment: Cut and paste is like drag and drop you have to copy paste

Comment: @NigelJoe I actually meant to delete that comment, as I re-read your question and I think I misunderstood it originally.   To clarify, you hooked HDD from laptop to desktop, copied files from desktop HDD to laptop HDD, and they looked good when viewing the laptop HDD.  You then plugged the laptop HDD back into the laptop, and those files are not showing.. am I following now? :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 :Yes, that is exactly what happened. Any help?

Comment: @yass  if  so, the files should still be in my desktop, right?

Comment: Not in your Desktop but try to search for it on the hard drive

Comment: @yass  But there is as much free space left as before the transfer happened. It is as if the system doesn't  read it. Assuming the files are there on the hard disk somewhere, would the filenames have changed?

Comment: Take a look at [Data Recovery](https://datarecovery.wondershare.com/recover-data/recover-files-lost-in-cut-and-paste.html) you can try it on your Desktop, you might have removed the Hard Drive before it has finish copying the files

Comment: If these were (relatively) small files and you didn't cleanly remove the laptop drive (giving the write cache time to commit data), they could have been "stuck" in the write cache of your machine or drive, and are lost now. If they are not on the desktop machine, they could be lost unless you can recovery them with a data recovery tool.

Comment: @acejavelin I did a clean removal. After copying I was able to open them from the hard drive while still connected  to the desktop

Comment: I have a feeling that if I reconnect my hard drive to the desktop I will be able to view them. But I cannot access my desktop for a week

Comment: File ownership issue?